# Including data files in cabal builds

Tags: haskell, cabal

I have a package with the following structure (okay, this is greatly simplified, but...)

```
app/
  src/
    Main.hs
  data/
    data.txt
  app.cabal
  Paths_app.hs
  Setup.hs
```

In Paths_app.hs I have:

```
module Paths_app where
getDataFileName :: FilePath -> IO FilePath
getDataFileName = return
```

and in Main.hs I have:

```
module Main where
import Paths_app
main = do
    file <- getDataFileName "data/data.txt"
    data <- readFile file
    putStrLn $ "Your data is: " ++ data
```

the relevant parts of my app.cabal file look like this:

```
name: app
version: 1.0
build-type: Simple
data-files: data/data.txt

executable foo
  build-depends: base, haskell98
  main-is: Main.hs
  hs-source-dirs: src
```

This builds fine (using `cabal configure` followed by `cabal install`) but the executable complains that it can't find the data.txt file. I've tried replacing the line

```
file <- getDataFileName "data/data.txt"
```

with

```
file <- getDataFileName "data.txt"
```

but the same thing occurs. Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you mentioned `Paths_app` in the `Other-modules` field?

Comment: Why do you have a Paths_app.hs? Isn't cabal supposed to create it?

Comment: @benmachine The one I have is a placeholder, so that I can run my code in interpreted mode - it just returns the current directory. When I build the code, it gets replaced by the cabal-generated one.

Comment: @hammar I didn't, although I do now and it still doesn't find my data files. Specifically, under the `executable` tag I have `other-modules: Paths_app`. I assume that is what you meant?

Comment: @ChrisTaylor: are you sure that the build isn't picking up your placeholder instead of the real file? Have you tried printing the result of getDataFileName to see what it says?

(as a side note, you could always run your code in ghci by using the -i option, possibly in a .ghci file)

Comment: @ChrisTaylor: Yes, though I can't seem to reproduce this either way. In both cases it ignores the placeholder file correctly. There might be something in your real package that interferes with this, however. Have you tried it with a simplified example like this one?

Comment: @hammar No, I'll go and do that now. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: @benmachine I should have thought of that. It's picking up the right version of `Paths_<packagename>`, as evidenced by this output: `Found directory: C:\Users\ctaylor\AppData\Roaming\cabal\haskeme-0.1\lib\stdlib.scm` though it still doesn't actually load the file. I'll have to investigate more. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Problem resolved: I'm building this on a Windows system, and when I used the filename returned by `getDataFileName` to load data into my program, I wasn't escaping the backslashes. Thanks for your help everyone! I'm not sure whether I should put this as an answer (since it's not really an answer to the question) or just delete the question.

Comment: Go ahead and answer it, why not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I was building on a Windows system, and when I used the filename returned by `getDataFileName` to load data into my program, I wasn't escaping the backslashes.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to reproduce it, but it works fine for me.

In the setup you describe, I had to drop the dependency on `haskell98` as both `base` and `haskell98` were providing `Prelude`. Furthermore, the file `Main` wouldn't compile as it used the keyword `data` as a variable name, so I renamed the variable to `dat`. But then it worked just fine.

Some info on my setup:

```
$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.4.1

$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 0.13.3
using version 1.14.0 of the Cabal library 

$ ls ~/.cabal/bin/
...  foo  ...   

$ ls ~/.cabal/share/app-1.0/data/
data.txt
```

Comment: I assume you're compiling on *nix? It turns out the problem was with escaping backslashes on Windows.

Comment: Ah, that figures. I compiled and run on Mac OS.